# Spectral Radiation Intensity and Energy Density

Tags: radiation, refraction, thermal-radiation, intensity

I'm trying to prove the following relation
$$ I_{v} = \frac{c}{n} u_{v} $$
where $I_{v}$ is the (spectral) radiation intensity and $u_{v}$ is the respective energy density, $n$ is the refractive index and $c$ is the speed of light in vacuum.

I've managed to show the following relation *in vacuum*:
$$ I_{v} = \frac{c}{4} u_{v} $$
but I'm not sure how to get to the final result.

In particular, I'm puzzled about about that factor of 4. I'm confident that the refractive index is easier to derive.

Could anyone provide any hints or advice on how to proceed for here?